# How can I atomically swap table names and its references in postgres without any issues?

Tags: postgresql, schema

I want to swap names of two tables with each other. TableA <> TableB. Also atomically to avoid any issues of read/writes. I know I can do that in a transction.

I am creating the table using - `CREATE TABLE TableB (LIKE TableA INCLUDING ALL);`. Then I am also copying over the FKs from from `A` to `B`. I am then doing a `INSERT INTO TABLEA....` to copy over the data as well (irrelevant for this). Once all of this is done, I rename the table using `ALTER TABLE RENAME` to swap the names `TableA` <> `TableB` in a transaction as well. So `TableA` becomes `TableA_Old` and `TableB` becomes the new `TableA` (example below)

However, this doesn't update the references to this new table in other tables, like `TableC` which still hold a FK against `TableA_Old`. When I do a `\d+` on the newly renamed table `TableA` (which was `TableB`) before, I don't see the references. They still point to `TableA_Old`.

Here is an example

**I create TableA**

```sql
CREATE TABLE TableA (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY
);


testdb=> \d TableA
                            Table "public.tablea"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |              Default               
--------+---------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 id     | integer |           | not null | nextval('tablea_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "tablea_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

**I create TableC with reference to TableA**

```sql
CREATE TABLE TableC(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    table_a_id INT,
   CONSTRAINT table_a_table_c_fk
      FOREIGN KEY(table_a_id) 
      REFERENCES TableA(id)
);


\d TableC
                              Table "public.tablec"
   Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |              Default               
------------+---------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 id         | integer |           | not null | nextval('tablec_id_seq'::regclass)
 table_a_id | integer |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "tablec_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "table_a_table_c_fk" FOREIGN KEY (table_a_id) REFERENCES tablea(id)
```

**You can see the reference**

**Now I create `TableB` that looks like `TableA` using a function**

```
create or replace function create_table_like(source_table text, new_table text)
returns void language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    rec record;
begin
    execute format(
        'create table %s (like %s including all)',
        new_table, source_table);
    for rec in
        select oid, conname
        from pg_constraint
        where contype = 'f' 
        and conrelid = source_table::regclass
    loop
        execute format(
            'alter table %s add constraint %s %s',
            new_table,
            replace(rec.conname, source_table, new_table),
            pg_get_constraintdef(rec.oid));
    end loop;
end $$;

select create_table_like('TableA', 'TableB');

\d TableB

testdb=> select create_table_like('TableA', 'TableB');
 create_table_like 
-------------------
 
(1 row)

testdb=> \d TableB

                            Table "public.tableb"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |              Default               
--------+---------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 id     | integer |           | not null | nextval('tablea_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "tableb_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

**Now I rename them**

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE TableA RENAME to TableA_OLD;
ALTER TABLE TableB RENAME to TableA;
COMMIT;
```

**Now when I look at the structures, the reference is still to `TableA_OLD` from `TableC`**

```
testdb=> \d TableA
                            Table "public.tablea"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |              Default               
--------+---------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 id     | integer |           | not null | nextval('tablea_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "tableb_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

testdb=> \d TableB



testdb=> \d TableA_old
                          Table "public.tablea_old"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |              Default               
--------+---------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 id     | integer |           | not null | nextval('tablea_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "tablea_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "tablec" CONSTRAINT "table_a_table_c_fk" FOREIGN KEY (table_a_id) REFERENCES tablea_old(id)
```

And `TableC` is pointing at the old table - `REFERENCES tablea_old(id)`

```
testdb=> \d TableC
                              Table "public.tablec"
   Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |              Default               
------------+---------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 id         | integer |           | not null | nextval('tablec_id_seq'::regclass)
 table_a_id | integer |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "tablec_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "table_a_table_c_fk" FOREIGN KEY (table_a_id) REFERENCES tablea_old(id)
```

Is there a safe way to do this without dropping and recreating the constraints again?

I know i can also update the `relfilenode` pointer in `pg_class` and swap them. However, that is risky since `TableB` could have a slightly different looking schema. So, I am wondering if I can update some other table in the system catalogue or use a DDL that wouldn't require dropping the constraint.

Comment: If you just want to *rename* them (not copy or anything), rename one (the first) to any name not a name of them both, rename the other (the second) to the original name of the first and then rename the first to the original name of the second.

Comment: Yeah thats what I am doing, and also copying the data, but i also want to update the references in other tables to the new Table. Thats not the case when I do `\d+ TableA` (after the rename), since the `References` aren't showing up from `TableC`

Comment: How does simple renaming change references let alone data so that you need to copy it? [Edit] the question and provide a [example] that shows that.

Comment: I updated the description with examples to replicate. Thank you!

To clarify - the references are pointing at the old table, i am trying to get them to point at the newly renamed table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The true identity of an object is its object ID, a number that is used to refer to the object in foreign key constraints an other internal database matters (with the notable exception of most function bodies). Renaming an object does not change its identity. You have to drop and re-create foreign key constraints.

Comment: Yeah thats what I was thinking. I am trying to avoid that. I saw that pg_repack and pg_squeeze update the data file (relfilenode) references. That would work here too right? As it will preserve the OID

Comment: It can work, but there are so many things you can break: visibility map, free space map, indexes, TOAST table all belong to the table. If you mess up anything, you would have data corruption. Don't do things like that by hand.

Comment: Yeah thats true! i am mostly following pg_repack and pg_squeeze there to account for the edge cases. In my situation dropping and adding oreign key constraint is also risky, since some of these tables can have millions of rows that can lead to locks and other issues.

Comment: I suppose I could disable the triggers on the table - remove and re-add the constrains and then add back the triggers in a single transaction. This will solve my issue for locks. Ex: `ALTER TABLE  DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;`

Comment: My only advice here is: hands off, unless you know PostgreSQL internals perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `rename table` command then automatically will be renamed all dependencies objects, foreign keys, references linked to this table. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE public.table1 RENAME TO table2;
```

Comment: I have mentioned an example in the question that shows how renaming using the method you showed leads to untouched references. @Laurenz Albe mentions in the other answer on how OID references lead to this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Using ALTER TABLE can swap names for tables without modifying the table structure itself. Running something like the code below can help when you need the backup to swith with the main table

```
ALTER TABLE myschema.tablemain RENAME TO old;
ALTER TABLE myschema.tablemain_backup RENAME TO tablemain;
ALTER TABLE myschema.old RENAME TO tablemain_backup;
```